# Can't enable SWV data trace timeline graph in STM IDE

Tags: stm32, debugging, stm32cubeide, stm

I am using STM32F401RE Nucleo board with STM IDE.
I am starting the SWV data trace graph window but the start trace option is not being enabled(I cant click on it).

I have attached pictures of debugging settings below.

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

Are there any more settings that I should  use or have I missed enabling anything?